# AttributeError: module 'peakutils' has no attribute 'indexes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, peakutils

I am trying to use peakutils to find the peak. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import peakutils
from peakutils import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

estimated_data = pd.read_csv("file", header=None)
col1 = estimated_data[:][0]  # First column data
col2 = estimated_data[:][1]  # Second column data

index = peakutils.indexes(col2, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)

plt.plot(col1, col2, lw=0.4, alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(col1[index], col2[index], marker="o", ls="", ms=3)

plt.show()
```

However, when I run it, it shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shengjie/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Coding/try.py", line 10, in <module>
    index = peakutils.indexes(col2, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)
AttributeError: module 'peakutils' has no attribute 'indexes'
```

I have tried to use python2.7 and python3.6 but it didn't work either way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Just use &quot;indexes()&quot; instead of &quot;peakutils.indexes()&quot;. I believe your `from peakutils import *` kind of overwrote the `import peakutils` line earlier. And so you dont need to call the `peakutils` as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do `import peakutils`, you don't need this line:

```
from peakutils import *
```

Remove that extra line and it should work.

Comment: The `from peakutils import <module_name>` is in my opinion better. I know the wildcard `*` is really bad, but you could have told him instead in my opinion.

Comment: I tried to make the imports match the code. But yes, you could also use `from peakutils import indexes` and change the code accordingly: `index = indexes(col2, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)`.

Comment: Hey Ronan, Thank you for your quick reply. I have tried both of your method, when I do from peakutils import indexes, it shows "cannot import name 'indexes' ". What else can I do? I use conda to install peakutils, and I am sure that the package is installed completely.

Comment: If you are sure, then the method `indexes()` just doesn&#39;t exist or you&#39;re spelling it wrongly. :) idk the peakutils library, maybe the problem is something else. :) @Tracy Gao

Comment: Maybe the "indexes()" module it is talking about uses this method from an inheritance that is not up to date on your platform, but has the same name ? Look into the source code of the library. It is easy finding specific keywords in random code.